# SELECT @@VERSION in Progress OpenEdge?

Tags: sql-injection, openedge, progress-db

I havent been able to find this in the docs so it may not exist - does openedge have a SELECT @@VERSION type of query to return the DB version?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason for the sql-injection tag?  It appears to be unrelated to the question?

Comment: Hi Tom - I am testing an app with Progress DB and generally i like to use SELECT VERSION type of commands for testing.

Comment: But what does that have to do with sql-injection?  Did auto-correct run amok or something?

Comment: if i find a sqli in an app with a progress DB having a simple command like SELECT VERSION to test with is useful.

Comment: i included the sqli tag since i am testing SQLi and in case another pentester is curious about this but unfamiliar with Progress

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the version indirectly by querying _dbstatus._dbStatus-ShmVers

The mapping of _dbStatus-ShmVers to actual version numbers is described in this kbase: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P39456

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such query that returns the OpenEdge database version. As an alternate, a  User Defined Function (UDF) can be written to return the version information. [This](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/P22074) article describes the ways to get OpenEdge database version. You can use one of these approaches in the UDF to get the database version. UDF examples can be found [here](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-development/page/Create-a-UDF.html).